# Using join fetch and group by in HQL query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have a `Report` entity that has a list of `ReportedTime` as `@OneToMany` relation. Each `ReportedTime` has a project, and `Project` has a manager.

The query itself (shown at the bottom) works fine. The problem is I need to now map these entities to DTOs and for that mapping purpose I need to know the projects that are in each `ReportedTime` in each `Report`. So I'm facing an n+1 problem, and I wanted to join fetch the reportedTimes and projects:

```sql
 @Query(value = "select " +
            "t as timesheetReport, " +
            "FUNCTION('string_agg', tlpa.username, ',') as projectManagersUsernames, " +
            "case when " +
            "   FUNCTION('string_agg', tlpa.username, ',') like concat('%', :username, '%') " +
            "then true else false " +
            "end as assigned " +
            "from TimesheetReport t " +
            "left join fetch t.reportedTimes rt " +
            "left join fetch rt.project p " +
            "left join p.teamLeaderAssignments tlp " +
            "left join tlp.account tlpa " +
            "group by t " +
            "having sum(rt.workTime)>0 " +
            "order by assigned desc ")
    List<IReportWithManagers> findAllWithManagers(String username, Pageable pageable);
```

but I get this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "reportedtimes1_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I tried to see the sql query in the logs and it seems that in this scenario Hibernate also puts the reported_time.id and project.id in the select clause but does not know how to group it? Is there way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because, of course, when fetching the joined entities, you're suddenly attempting to select a whole bunch of new columns that are neither included in `GROUP BY` nor aggregated.

To be able to select columns from `rt` and `p`, you would need to `GROUP BY t, rt, p`, which unfortunately (as far as I understand) changes the semantics of the query. I'd try adding separate `JOINS` for fetching and grouping:

```
left join t.reportedTimes rt
left join rt.project p
left join fetch t.reportedTimes rt2
left join fetch rt.project p2
left join p.teamLeaderAssignments tlp
left join tlp.account tlpa
group by t, rt2, p2
having sum(dt.workTime)>0
order by assigned desc
```

The problem with the above is, duplicate rows will now enter the aggregation, so perhaps you could use `ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT tlpa.username, ',')` or select the array and join the strings in Java (not sure if Hibernate supports selecting PostgreSQL arrays out of the box, though, you'd need to check).

Please be advised that I haven't tried the above solution, so I cannot guarantee it will work.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not so sure `GROUP BY t, rt, p` changes the semantics. What is `dt` in `HAVING sum(dt.workTime)>0`? Was the alias supposed to be `rt` instead?

Comment: Yes, `dt` should be `rt`, I will edit that. When I try the double join as shown here I get `org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list `. I tried just grouping by t, rt, p but then I get duplicate entries for each reportedTime in each report. I would need an equivalent of `distinct on()` in hibernate so I could use distinct on report.id, but hibernate does not support `disctinct on ()`

Comment: Well, in that case, I'm afraid you'll have to use a native query